# Fourier coefficient of $f(x) = e^{imx}$ and $g(x) = \cos(mx)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, trigonometric-integrals

Let $f,g$ be the functions that can be seen on the title. Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. I need to
$$S_k[f](x) = \sum_{n=-k}^{k}\hat{f}(n)e^{inx} \ \ \text{and} \ \ S_k[g](x) = \sum_{n=-k}^{k}\hat{g}(n)e^{inx}.$$
I would like to know if my calculation is correct. Furthermore, I can't seem to find the Fourier coefficients of $g(x)$. This is how I did the calculation:

\begin{align*}
\hat{f}(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(m-n)x}dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2i\pi(m-n)}(e^{i(m-n)\pi}-e^{i(m-n)\pi})\\
&= \frac{1}{2i\pi(m-n)}\cdot 2i\sin((m-n)\pi) = 0 \ \ \ \ \ \text{for} \ m \neq n
\end{align*}
For $m =n$, we have $\hat{f}(n) = 1$. My guts telling me that this is incorrect. Can someone please verify?

As for $g$, I'm not sure how to do it
\begin{align*}
\hat{g}(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(mx)e^{-inx}dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\left(-\frac{1}{in}\left[\cos(mx)e^{-inx}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} - \frac{m}{in}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)e^{-inx}dx\right)\\
&=-\frac{m}{2\pi in}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)e^{-inx}dx\\
&= -\frac{m}{2\pi in}\left(-\frac{1}{in}\left[\sin(mx)e^{-inx}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} + \frac{m}{in}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(mx)e^{-inx}dx\right)\\
&= \frac{m^2}{2\pi n^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(mx)e^{-inx}dx\end{align*}
It seems to me that there is no end to this. So I was wondering if I did it wrong, or maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: How about $\hat{g}(n)$?

Comment: To take care of $\hat{g}(n)$, write $\cos(mx)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{imx}+e^{-imx})$, and use what you've already done.